# React JS using useEffect as componentDidMount hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working on a React JS application. I am using functional components and react hooks in my application. I am figuring out the componentDidMount counterpart in hooks.

This is my code

```
const Items = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(); //this function is being called whenever the state is updated. I am looking for componentDidMount counterpart
    return () => {
      //clean up
    }
  })

  return (
     //return the view component
  )
}
```

As you can see in the component, I want to move the function call into componentDidMount counterpart for hooks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useEffect vs Component life cycle methods

```js
 const [data, setData]=useState("")
 const [inpVal, setInpVal]= useState("")
 
 useEffect(() => {
 fetchItems(inpVal);
  },[]); //if you put an empty array then it will act as componentdidmount
  
  useEffect(() => {
fetchItems(inpVal);
  },[inpVal]); //if you put an inpVal in array then it will act as componentDidUpdate which means when ever the inpVal change useeffect will run
```

Answer (score 2):

You should simply add an empty array of dependencies to your `useEffect` call.

```js
const Items = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(); //this function is being called whenever the state is updated. I am looking for componentDidMount counterpart
    return () => {
      //clean up
    }
  }, []) // <-- add this

  return (
     //return the view component
  )
}
```